# google maps Get Latitude and Longitude from zip code

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to get longitude and latitude using google api just passing zip/postal code ?

Thanks for any hints, bye

Answer (score 28):

Simply create an instance of [`google.maps.Geocoder`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Geocoder) and call its `geocode` method, passing in an object that possesses the attributes necessary for it to be a [`GeocoderRequest`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#GeocoderRequest).

Thus:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({address: /* zip you got from user input */},
    function(results_array, status) { 
        // Check status and do whatever you want with what you get back
        // in the results_array variable if it is OK.
        // var lat = results_array[0].geometry.location.lat()
        // var lng = results_array[0].geometry.location.lng()
});
```

Comment: I get `ZERO RESULTS` every time I try just a zip code.

Comment: You could try adding [`region`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#GeocoderRequest) to your request and see if that helps Google disambiguate the value.

Answer (score 14):

You can use this alternately :

**URL** : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=santa+cruz&components=postal_code:695564&sensor=false

Simply call this url in a jquery-ajax and you will get the lat long in result.

**Example using jquery-ajax** :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var zipcode = 695564;

    $.ajax({
       url : "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=santa+cruz&components=postal_code:"+zipcode+"&sensor=false",
       method: "POST",
       success:function(data){
           latitude = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
           longitude= data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
           alert("Lat = "+latitude+"- Long = "+longitude);
       }

    });
});
```

**Sample JSON result from google api :**

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "695564",
               "short_name" : "695564",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Thiruvananthapuram",
               "short_name" : "TVM",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kerala",
               "short_name" : "KL",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Kerala 695564, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 8.5894172,
                  "lng" : 77.0210912
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 8.5616185,
                  "lng" : 76.96664299999999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 8.5753702,
               "lng" : 76.99310740000001
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 8.5894172,
                  "lng" : 77.0210912
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 8.5616185,
                  "lng" : 76.96664299999999
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Cheers..

Comment: i tried http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code:530016&sensor=false   its working grate

Comment: @roy it's working great!. Is there any limitation/restrictions for this API key to use? like no. of requests from the same IP or no. of hits to the API? I heard google will block IP s if several requests comes from same IP?

Comment: @krishnamohan  Google wont block, but the free usage is about 1000 requests per day or so. I am not sure about the limit. Hope you have upvoted if found useful..;)

Comment: Thanks @RoyMJ Yeah, sometimes I get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error. So I've created an API key and using it. BTW I forgot to up vote you and  did now. Thank you ;)